# Create a tag synonym for [observer-pattern] and related tags

Tags: discussion, status-declined, synonym-request

Can we have tag synonyms made for:

- [observer-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/observer-pattern) - 932, has wiki
- [observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/observable) - 289, no wiki
- [observers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/observers) - 198, no wiki

Answer (score 2):

No thanks, `observable` questions are largely referring to the name of an API rather than the general pattern concept.